# Base feature module of Android Instant Apps

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

Hi I am reading documents of Android Instant apps. I came across this statement here [Project structure for Instant Apps](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/structure.html)

> When built into an instant app, this module builds a feature APK. When built into an installed app, the base feature module produces an AAR file.

As I see, there is no option in Android Studio to built instant app or installed app differently? What they mean here?

Comment: You might want to expand on your question further, as I'm not sure what specifically you are trying to do or why you would want a different build behavior.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I think I found which I was looking. See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what I was looking.

[image]

Comment: LoL ! Good for you :)